# python dictionary item reference assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

Usually I've seen a similar behaviour when I don't want it, but this time I like to have a variable assigned to an (integer) item of a dictionary and when the value is changed in any of both I like to apply in both.

That is to say, having a dictionary:

```
>>> a_dict = {'v':1,'r':0}
>>> r_int = a_dict['r']
```

Then the variable *r* doesn't have the same reference even it's the same value. When assign to r, a['r'] will still have the *0* and viceversa.

But just what I'm trying to find is how can I pass this *r* to another object and its changes be updated in the main *a* dictionary?

If the item is a list, the assignment to *r* is the list and changing the elements of this list can be saw in *a* because in fact is the same list object. To avoid that I use copy, but in this case I need the opposite. I like to see:

```
>>> r_int = 2
>>> a_dict
{'v':1,'r':2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment doesn't work like that in Python. Reassigning a name like `r` to a different value will never affect any other bindings.

The only way to make this work is to mutate the contents of something mutable, for example a list:

```
a = {'v': 1, 'r': [0]}
r = a_dict['r']
r[0] = [2]
```

but that obviously introduces an extra level. Much better, unless you have a very good reason, to just use the dict itself.

Comment: The fact is that I have to have an integer in this _r_ variable. From where its value is used, I cannot change it to manage a list of one element. I can have a reference to _r_ to refresh the dictionary from the dictionary owner, but I hope there would be a more elegant alternative.

Comment: @srgblnch there isn't; if you want to "change" an immutable object in a mutable container, you have to replace it: `a_dict['r'] = 2`. Have a read through e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Well, then my best option is to have an 'updater' in the dictionary owner, who also can remember _r_, to propagate changes. But this also requires to grant a single point access. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `r[0] = 2` instead of `r[0] = [2]`?